# Pandas creating columns by multiplying other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t0_p0':[1,2,3], 't1_p0':[1,2,3], 't2_p0':[1,2,3], 't0_p1':[1,2,3], 't1_p1':[1,2,3], 't2_p1':[1,2,3], 't0_p3':[1,2,3], 't1_p3':[1,2,3], 't2_p3':[1,2,3], 'Month_1':[1,0,0],'Month_2':[0,1,0] 'Hour_1':[1,0,0],'Hour_2':[0,1,0], 'x_1':[0,1,1], 'holid':[2,7,8]})
```

With the dataframe above, I want to multiply columns Month and hours by each of the other columns. For example, t0_p0 * Month_1, t0_p0 * Month_2, ..., 't2_P3'* Month_2, and same for Hours. I will not multiply month by the hour.

and the results of multiplications should be added to a new column named as follows, Month1_t0_p0 or Hour2_t2_p3. so basically names of two columns multiplied put together.

what would be the pythonic way of doing this. I know how to multiply columns like:

```
df['Month1_t0_p0'] = df['Month_1'] * df['t0_p0']
```

However, I am not sure how to automatically select the columns I want to multiply and create and name columns in the way I described above.

Comment: Would you know how to generate a list of the column names using string formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'t0_p0':[1,2,3],
                   't1_p0':[1,2,3],
                   't2_p0':[1,2,3],
                   't0_p1':[1,2,3],
                   't1_p1':[1,2,3],
                   't2_p1':[1,2,3],
                   't0_p3':[1,2,3],
                   't1_p3':[1,2,3],
                   't2_p3':[1,2,3],
                   'Month_1':[1,0,0],
                   'Month_2':[0,1,0],
                   'Hour_1':[1,0,0],
                   'Hour_2':[0,1,0],
                   'x_1':[0,1,1],
                   'holid':[2,7,8]})

cols_tp = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('t')]
cols_m = df.columns[df.columns.str.lower().str.startswith('m')]

for col_tp in cols_tp:
    for col_m in cols_m:
        df[col_m + '_' +  col_tp] = df[col_m] * df[col_tp]


df
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as a starter: Create a new df with only those columns you want to multiply with, then iterate over that new df. By concatenation create the final df with the new columns and those you didnt want to multiply with. I am not sure though how to automatically generate the name of the columns, nor do I have the exact code for the iteration. Sorry for that. As said, maybe a starter.